# htmlentities関数を使うと、なぜ日本語文字列が消えてしまうのか？

Tags: php, centos

PHP超初心者です。

現在、問い合わせフォームを作っているのですが上手くいかない箇所があります。

```
function Conv2HtmlSpecialChars($value)
{
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            $value[$k] = Conv2HtmlSpecialChars($v);
        }
    } else {
        $value = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }

    return $value;

}
```

という関数があります。

そして、PHPファイルの中で、

```
$dataArray = Conv2HtmlSpecialChars($dataArray);
```

という使い方をします。

上記の`$dataArray`という配列変数には、例えば、

```
$dataArray['氏名'] = "あいうえお";
$dataArray['フリガナ'] = "アイウエオ";
$dataArray['郵便番号'] = "999-9999";
$dataArray['住所'] = "東京都大田区";
$dataArray['E-mailアドレス'] = "test_test@example.com";
$dataArray['お問い合わせ内容'] = "お尋ねしたいことがあります";
```

がセットされているとします。

そして実際に、PHPを動かしてみると・・・

```
$dataArray['氏名'] => ""
$dataArray['フリガナ'] => ""
$dataArray['郵便番号'] => "999-9999"
$dataArray['住所'] => ""
$dataArray['E-mailアドレス'] => "test_test@example.com"
$dataArray['お問い合わせ内容'] => ""
```

というように日本語の文字列が消えて、英数字だけしか残りません。

```
htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

でキチンと`UTF-8`を指定しているのに、なぜ日本語文字列が消えてしまうのでしょうか？

原因をご存知の方、原因と適切な対処方法をご教授いただきたく存じます。
もし、上記で私がチンプンカンプンなことを記述していたら、そこもご指定願います。

**開発環境**

- レンタルサーバー（CentOS 5）
- PHP（5.2.16）
- 作業環境（Windows7pro）
- PHP編集用（NoEditor）

P.S.
　他に誰も開発経験がなくPHPが分かる人が１人もいない中、何とか頑張っています。
　何卒、ご協力よろしくお願い致します。

======================== 以下続報 ========================

問題となっている`Conv2HtmlSpecialChars関数`に以下のようなデバッグを仕掛けました。

```
  function Conv2HtmlSpecialChars($value)
    {

echo'<hr /><pre>fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_Start --> ';var_dump( $value );echo'</pre>';

        if (is_array($value)) {
            foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
                $value[$k] = Conv2HtmlSpecialChars($v);
            }
        } else {
            $value = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

echo'<hr /><pre>htmlentities_value --> ';var_dump( $value );echo'</pre>';

        }

echo'<hr /><pre>fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_End --> ';var_dump( $value );echo'</pre>';

        return $value;
    }
```

その結果、以下のように出力されました。
※文字化けしている箇所は無視してください。

```
fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_Start --> array(9) {
  ["羂���"]=>
  string(10) "武田　進言"
  ["��������"]=>
  string(16) "タケダ　シンゲン"
  ["�灸梢���"]=>
  string(8) "788-9999"
  ["篏���"]=>
  string(12) "東京都台東区"
  ["�肢����"]=>
  string(12) "03-9999-9999"
  ["E-mail�≪������"]=>
  string(21) "test-test@example.com"
  ["E-mail�≪������(腆肴���)"]=>
  string(21) "test-test@example.com"
  ["��������������絎�"]=>
  string(32) "テストコメント１テストコメント２"
  ["date"]=>
  string(27) "2015/03/03 Tuesday 23:59:29"
}

fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_Start --> string(10) "武田　進言"

htmlentities_value --> string(0) ""

fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_End --> string(0) ""

fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_Start --> string(16) "タケダ　シンゲン"

htmlentities_value --> string(0) ""

fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_End --> string(0) ""

fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_Start --> string(8) "788-9999"

htmlentities_value --> string(8) "788-9999"

fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_End --> string(8) "788-9999"

fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_Start --> string(12) "東京都台東区"

htmlentities_value --> string(0) ""

fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_End --> string(0) ""

fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_Start --> string(12) "03-9999-9999"

htmlentities_value --> string(12) "03-9999-9999"

fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_End --> string(12) "03-9999-9999"

fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_Start --> string(21) "test-test@example.com"

htmlentities_value --> string(21) "test-test@example.com"

fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_End --> string(21) "test-test@example.com"

fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_Start --> string(21) "test-test@example.com"

htmlentities_value --> string(21) "test-test@example.com"

fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_End --> string(21) "test-test@example.com"

fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_Start --> string(32) "テストコメント１テストコメント２"

htmlentities_value --> string(0) ""

fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_End --> string(0) ""

fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_Start --> string(27) "2015/03/03 Tuesday 23:59:29"

htmlentities_value --> string(27) "2015/03/03 Tuesday 23:59:29"

fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_End --> string(27) "2015/03/03 Tuesday 23:59:29"

fuction_Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_End --> array(9) {
  ["羂���"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["��������"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["�灸梢���"]=>
  string(8) "788-9999"
  ["篏���"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["�肢����"]=>
  string(12) "03-9999-9999"
  ["E-mail�≪������"]=>
  string(21) "test-test@example.com"
  ["E-mail�≪������(腆肴���)"]=>
  string(21) "test-test@example.com"
  ["��������������絎�"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["date"]=>
  string(27) "2015/03/03 Tuesday 23:59:29"
```

やはり、

```
$value = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

のロジックを通ると値が消えていって英数字のみ通過できるようです。

何故このような動きになるのか、何かひらめいたことがあったらご教授ください。

======================== 以下続報２（解決！） ========================

コードを以下のようにしました。

```
function Conv2HtmlSpecialChars($value)
{
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            $value[$k] = Conv2HtmlSpecialChars($v);
         }
    } else {

           $value = mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8');
           $value = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

        }
    return $value;
}
```

要するに、

`$value = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`

の関数で悩んでいたのですが、この関数すぐ上に、

```
$value = mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8');
```

を追加して値を`UTF-8`に変換するようにしました。

この方法が正しいかはよく分からないのですが、この方法で上手くロジックが動作するようになったので、結果オーライにしたいと思います。
もう少しキレイにコードの記述方法をまとめられたらいいのですが、現在の私の力量ではこれが精一杯です。

Comment: その日本語文字列はUTF-8ですか？

Comment: 問い合わせフォームから入力した文字を変数にセットする仕様なのですが、フォームから入力した文字列がUTF-8なのかまでは分かりません。ただ、PHPファイルというかHTMLファイルにPHPコードを記述しているのですが、HTMLファイルは「UTF8N」となっております。（これは関係ないですか？）

Comment: エンコーディングは`mb_detect_encoding`で調べることができます。

Comment: HTML の Form タグでは `accept-charset="UTF-8"` で POST 送信する文字列の文字コードを指定することができます。基本的に Apache サーバがその HTML を UTF-8 としてレスポンスしているなら Form で送信される文字列も UTF-8 になるはずです。

Comment: @Web_beginner さん ふと気づいたのですが、これを PHP ファイルの先頭に差し込むといいかもしれません。`error_reporting(-1);ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );` これでエラーが表示されるようになります。 [display_errors  参考URL](http://www.24w.jp/study_contents.php?bid=php&iid=php&sid=setting&cid=001) [error_repporting 参考URL](http://www.gesource.jp/weblog/?p=4541)

Comment: @Web_beginner さん 解決できたようで何よりです！ ご自身の力で解決できたようなので、この質問に対してご自分で回答 (解決できた内容を記載) し、その回答に解決済みのチェックをつけてください。そうすることで後から見た人がどういった手段で解決したのかが分かるようになります。

Comment: @Shirone様、ありがとうございます。ちなみにかなり初歩的な質問なのですが、「解決済みのチェックをつける」とはどういうことをすればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: @Web_beginner さん これは決して強制ではありませんが、[回答の承認](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) をすることができます。 `回答の横にあるチェックマークをクリックしてグレー表示からチェック済みに切り替えます。` 今回の場合は Web_begginer さんがご自身で回答を記載し、48時間以上経過した後で、その回答にチェックマークを付けることでこの質問が解決されたものであることを明示することが可能です。

Comment: @Shirone様 48時間以上経ったらチェックマークを付けることができるようになるのですね。承知しました。48時間以上経った状態を待ってみます。また、不明なことがあったら質問させていただきます。

Comment: @Web_beginner さん 宜しくお願いします。あと今回の解決方法で、おそらく [以前の質問](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/7254/7926) も解決している気がしておりますので、一度確認してみて頂けますでしょうか。(解決済みでしたら申し訳ありません…)

Comment: @Shirone様、すみません・・・　探してみましたが、どこにチェックすればよいのでしょうか？　「解決済み」にしたいので、やり方を教えてください。

Comment: @Web_beginner さん [自分の質問に回答できますか?](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) を参考にしてみてください。私は自分の質問に自分で回答したことがないため、48 時間後にどう見えるのかが分かりませんが、恐らく Web_begginer さんが書き込んだ回答に灰色のチェックマークがあると思いますが、いかがでしょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決をしたので、質問に追記した内容のコピペになりますが、以下の通り報告します。

コードを以下のようにしました。

```
function Conv2HtmlSpecialChars($value)
{
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            $value[$k] = Conv2HtmlSpecialChars($v);
         }
    } else {

           $value = mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8');
           $value = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

        }
    return $value;
}
```

要するに、

```
$value = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

の関数で悩んでいたのですが、この関数すぐ上に、

```
$value = mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8');
```

を追加して値を`UTF-8`に変換するようにしました。

この方法が正しいかはよく分からないのですが、この方法で上手くロジックが動作するようになったので、結果オーライにしたいと思います。
もう少しキレイにコードの記述方法をまとめられたらいいのですが、現在の私の力量ではこれが精一杯です。

------------------ その後の見解 ------------------
PHP.iniというのがあるのを知ったのですが、これを・・・

```
mbstring.language=Japanese
mbstring.internal_encoding="UTF-8"
mbstring.http_output="UTF-8"
```

というように設定しておけば済む話だったようです。
なんともむなしい独り相撲でした。

Answer (score 4):

おそらく `$dataArray` に格納されたデータの文字コードが　UTF-8 以外になっています。

当方環境(CentOS6,PHP5.6)で確認したところ、文字コードが UTF-8 でないものを `htmlentities()` に通したら空文字となりました。
`htmlentities()` の[公式ドキュメント](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.htmlentities.php)を見てみると以下のように書いてありました。

> 入力文字列の中に、指定した encoding で無効な符号単位シーケンスが含まれる場合は、 ENT_IGNORE あるいは
>   ENT_SUBSTITUTE フラグが設定されていない限りは空文字列を返します。

ただし、`ENT_IGNORE` 定数は `PHP5.3 から、`ENT_SUBSTITUTE` 定数は PHP5.4 から使用可能ですので、Web_beginner さんの環境では使用できません。

なので、`$dataArray` のデータ (POSTされたデータでしょうか？) を UTF-8 にすると、正常にデータとして変換できると思います。

---

### 補足

検証に使ったコードは以下の通りです。
以下のコードは UTF-8 の文字エンコーディングで記述されています。

```
include dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'data.php';

function Conv2HtmlSpecialChars( $value )
{
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            $value[$k] = Conv2HtmlSpecialChars($v);
        }
    } else {
        $value = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES);
    }

    return $value;

}    
var_dump( Conv2HtmlSpecialChars($dataArray) );
```

include で読み込んだ `data.php` に以下の定義がしてあります。
`data.php` の文字エンコーディングは Shift_JIS を指定しました。

```
$dataArray['氏名'] = "あいうえお";
$dataArray['フリガナ'] = "アイウエオ";
$dataArray['郵便番号'] = "999-9999";
$dataArray['住所'] = "東京都大田区";
$dataArray['E-mailアドレス'] = "test_test@example.com";
$dataArray['お問い合わせ内容'] = "お尋ねしたいことがあります";
```

表示結果が、以下の通りです。
[image: 文字が消えた再現のスクショ]

data.php を UTF-8 に変換すると、ちゃんと表示されました。
[image: 文字がちゃんと表示された再現のスクショ]

---

## 追記

デバッグコード中の値を表示している箇所の一番最初の `Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_$v_Start` と、最後の `htmlentities_$value` の出力は配列ではない場合があります。

`Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_$v_Start` は例でいえば "竹田　徹夜" だったり "222-3333" だったりするはずです。
また、`htmlentities_$value` の値は `htmlentities()` からの返り値のはずなので、絶対に配列にはなりません。

その為、誤った index のデータを表示しているような気がします。

このように配列か文字列か動的に変化してしまう変数を見る場合は
`echo'<hr /><pre>Conv2HtmlSpecialChars_$v_Start --> ';var_dump( $value );echo'</pre>';`
ぐらいにしておいたほうが良いと思います。

---

追記2 ：本回答のまとめとなります。

当初回答したとおり、やはり文字化けが原因だと思われます。
文字化けした場合、場合によっては ASCII 制御コードなどが紛れ込んでしまう(誤って解釈されてしまう) 可能性もあり、様々な意図しない挙動を示すことがあります。
なので、ここはまず文字化けしないように環境を整える必要があります。
(実際、私の環境では UTF-8 で揃えて以前つけたスクリーンショットのように正常にデータが表示・処理されておりますので)

1. HTML 上の form タグにて `accept-charset="UTF-8"` を記述してみて頂けますでしょうか？
2. HTML の meta タグにて、`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` を指定してみてください。
3. PHP ファイル、HTML ファイル等、基本的にどんなファイルであれ UTF-8N (BOMなしです) で保存してください。
4. PHP の内部エンコーディングや出力エンコーディングを UTF-8 にしてください。
   参考：[以前の質問 対処法 1. PHP の設定ファイルを変更する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/7256/7926)をご覧ください

以上となります。

Comment: Shirone様、毎度ご丁寧な回答ありがとうございます。本当に助かります。
私、今回のロジックをじっくり見直して気づいたですが、is_arrayが存在しているを見逃していました。ですので、デバッグして「$value[$k] = Conv2HtmlSpecialChars($v);」の方がどういう動きをするのか調べたところ、なぜか配列変数に入っている値をこのロジックが消していっていることが分かりました。このロジックは他から拾ってきたものなのですが、なぜ値を消していっているのかが不明です。
なお、$value = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');の方のロジックもデバッグしたのですが、こちらは「2」という値を返してきます。
なぜ、こういう動きになるのかお分かりになりますでしょうか？

Comment: @Web_beginner さん そうなると、一度 `Conv2HtmlSpecialChars()` に渡すデータを `var_dump()` するなりして、質問文に追記して頂いても良いでしょうか？(もちろん他の文字に置き換えてもらって構いませんが、配列の構造だけはそのままでお願いします) この `Conv2HtmlSpecialChars()` というロジックは何次元の配列であっても全ての要素に `htmlentities()` を適用する動作をします。よって、最終的に全ての要素が `htmlentities()` を通りますので、空文字列になってしまう理由は POST された文字列が UTF-8 ではなかったのだと思われます。 `htmlentities()` が 2 を返す、といった現象には遭遇したことがありません…。一応確認ですが、`$value = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');の方のロジックもデバッグしたのですが、こちらは「2」という値を返してきます` というのは、つまり "$value に 2 が入っていた" という認識で間違いないですか？

Comment: @Shirone様、かしこまりました。今、現在デバッグコードだらけで表示が汚い状況ですので、少し整理して出力結果を追記させていただきます。
$valueに2をセットをしていないのですが、何故か「2」という数字がデバッグで表示されます。これについても追記させていただきます。

Comment: かなり長文にはなりましたが、デバッグした様子を追記してみました。
これで何か分かれば幸いです。

Comment: @Web_beginner `var_dump()` の出力を受けて返答しました。御確認をお願いします。

Comment: @Shirone様、長々とデバッグを書いてしまい申し訳ありません。とにかく情報が欲しくて、我を忘れていました。今、冷静になってみると、何とひどい追記をしてしまったのか反省しています。でも、動的に変化するデバッグの方法を教えていただいたので、また知識が増えたことは喜ばしいと思っています。この方法でしたら色んなところで使えそうです。

Comment: @Shirone様、ご教授いただいた簡潔なデバッグ文を用いて、再実行してみました。昨日の汚いデバッグ情報は削除して、割と分かりやすくしたつもりです。今回追記した箇所をご参照いただいて何か分かったら教えていただきたく存じます。

Comment: @Shirone様、一応解決しました。質問文に「以下続報２（解決！）」を追記しました。よかったらご参照ください。たったこれだけの問題でまるまる２日かかってしまいました。あぁ、情けないです・・・